# How to pass data from DataGridView to table in ReportViewer without Database or Dataset

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, reportviewer

I have a few `DataGridView` tables which user fills (I don't use any `Dataset` or `Database` here).
I need to pass them to `ReportViewer`, I want exact the same tables in report as in a form, no changes at all.

I tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("rds1", Form1.dgv1.DataSource)
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
```

and in *report1.rdlc* added a table and set it dataset name to rds1 but it generates error

```
The table ‘table1’ refers to an invalid DataSetName ‘rds1’.
```

So I guess I need to make a `DataSet` from my `DataGridView` tables.

How would you suggest me to do that? Otherwise, is there any simpler way to pass the table to report?

Comment: have you created an actual dataset definition in the report itself? it should have all the fields expected from your dgv datasource (name and type)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335424/how-do-i-export-a-datagridview-to-reportviewer?rq=1

Comment: You mean something like:    
 
       Dim dt As New DataTable("dt1")
          With dt
              .Columns.Add("col1")
              .Columns.Add("col2")

          End With

          For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Form1.dgv1.Rows
              dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("col1").Value, dr.Cells("col2").Value)
          Next



      
          Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("dgv1", dt)

          Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    
  still geting the same error

Comment: ok, fixed it, what i did:

1) I added a DataSet MyNewDataSet (Project > Add New Item > DataSet) and created a DataTable with columns named the same as in my dgv in this DataSet

2) I added this DataSet to Report (Report > Data Sources > Add)

3) right click on table in report > properties > select MyNewDataSetName from dataset name dropdownlist

4) drag&drop columns from Solution Explorer>Data Sources>MyNewDataSetName to table in report

and thats it, thanks for help Vland :)

Comment: Hey szooky, I did all what you said but still having problem. Can't get data from DatagridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a DataSet to your report `.rldc` **Data Sources** list and drag and drop the columns into your report element (table, tablix, list etc.)

Remember you can add any kind of object from your project to your report as Data Source (basically any `Public Class` you create). The imported names and types will be taken from the class properties.